# CSS Font shorthand?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I was basically trying to abbreviate "font-style" to just "font" by using the shorthand property. However, it only seems to work if I specify other properties (size/line height/font-family) too on the same selector.

If I comment out any additional specification, the "italic" is ignored! Am I missing something here or am I just not supposed to use

```
.main{font:italic;}
```

instead of (for instance)

```
.main{font-style:italic;}
```

or

```
.main{
font:italic 1em/1.2em georgia,"times new roman",serif;}
```

So, what's the minimum requirements for using the font shorthand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [font-family](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/font-family) and [font-size](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/font-size) are the minimum styles required for this style property.

**Example:**

```
font: 1em "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

An example of a full shorthand would be the following:

```
font: bold italic small-caps 1em/1.5em verdana,sans-serif
```

This would replace the original code below:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.5em;
font-family: verdana,sans-serif
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this imply that my attempt [.main{font:italic;}] is simply ignored altogether by CSS?

Comment: @pythonforspss.org: Correct.

Answer (score 2):

minimal specifications are size and font-name.
In your case it will look like this:

```
.main{
 font: 1em  verdana;
}
```