# Can I use font:monospace?

Tags: html, css

It seems it doesn't work if I use font:monospace.
But It's worked for font-family:monospace.
What's the difference beteew font and font-family?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Font shorthand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704192/css-font-shorthand)

Comment: it does work, i had use font:10px monospace; n it is working fine for me

Comment: @JennieZong Did any of the answers below answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

You need to atleast specify `font-size` while specifying the shorthand property for font along with the family. Otherwise everything will have its own initial values.

See the [definition below](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font).

> [ [ <‘font-style’> ||  || <‘font-weight’> || <‘font-stretch’> ]? **<‘font-size’>** [ / <‘line-height’> ]? **<‘font-family’>** ] | caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar

An example:

```
selector{
   font:12px monospace;
}
```

When specifying shorthand property using `font` font-size must precede font-family and both are mandatory (the ones in angle brackets and not in square brackets) atleast.

Comment: The statement “Otherwise everything will be reset to the defaults” is not correct; the declaration `font: monospace` is invalid, thus ignored (it does not reset anything). The suggestion `font:12px monospace` is misleading, since the question does not refer to setting font size to any specific value. Even `font: 100% monospace` could unintentionally change the font size (from what it would otherwise be for an element). If you want to set only font family, then you should say `font-family: monospace`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela True, fixed the statement. Thanks. Btw OP knows that he needs to use font-family, he was asking why it did not work for font shorthand. This was an answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

[Font](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp) is the shorthand looking for several properties.  Example:

```
p
{
font:15px arial,sans-serif;
}
```

While [font-family](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp) is just looking for the actual font.  Example:

```
p
{
font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;
}
```